# Left and top padding for CheckBox doesn't work

Tags: android, layout, padding

I want to create layout for Custom Adapter. It should be line with checkbox, icon and textView.

I use next layout xml configuration for row:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkboxFileSelect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_icon"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:checked="false"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/folder_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/folder_icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_folder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

but left and top padding doesn't work. When I add left and right padding it only increase right padding value.

example image here

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `android:layout_marginLeft` for this usecase.

Padding is the space inside the component. e.g: space between the text and the border of TextView.

Margin is the space outside the components. e.g: space between left edge of the screen and border of your component

Comment: Thanks for so quick response.

Comment: The problem is that margin will make the "margined area" not clickable for the checkbox. I need it clickable and thus want to use padding, but it doesn't move the checkbox at all.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party but here's a solution for anyone seeking a way to do it. Since there's no way you can move the check box itself without adding margin, you can override the class:

```
class PaddedCheckBox @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyle: Int = android.R.attr.checkboxStyle,
) : MaterialCheckBox(context, attrs, defStyle) {
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        val rtlCoefficient = if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(this) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) -1 else 1
        canvas.save()
        canvas.translate(rtlCoefficient * 40f, 0f)
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.restore()
    }
}
```

You can extend your view from `AppComptCheckBox` itself in case you're not using material components.

**Note:** Consider adding excessive padding end to your check box to compensate the canvas translation.

Answer (score 2):

One way I found to accomplish this is to "repackage" the `CheckBox`'s button drawable with insets. In Kotlin:

```
myCheckbox.buttonDrawable = InsetDrawable(myCheckbox.buttonDrawable, leftPadding, 0, 0, 0)
```

...where `leftPadding` is the amount of padding you want to add.

Comment: Be aware of that. I've spotted that at lower API for example 24, it is causing checkbox default animation to stop in between states. Then the checkbox behaviour is really weird. Look here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72772473/android-emulator-checkbox-and-radio-button-bug-various-incorrect-states-are-sh